# serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port, raspbian, pyserial

I have a Raspberry that I am trying to connect to a Ubidots IOT cloud but I got this error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Downloads/raspbiDaniela/Ver 2016/ZonrProject $ python main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "main.py", line 124, in <module>
        main()
      File "main.py", line 21, in main
        ser = serial.Serial(port=port, baudrate=baud)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 261, in __init__
        self.open()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 278, in open
        raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
    serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port /dev/ttyAMA0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyAMA0'
```

Comment: run with sudo ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to run the script every time with sudo as suggested in the comments but you need to make sure that you have read/write permissions for `/dev/ttyAMA0`. You can modify the permisions using:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

If the device is detachable, you may also consider creating an `udev` rule which will apply correct permissions each time you connect it. You can read more about `udev` rules at [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/udev).

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when I turn on SSH over serial. When I turn it off and only turn on serial interface through `sudo raspi-config`, everything works fine without permission problems.

Hope it helps other developers.