# unable to open port with pySerial - serial.Serial

Tags: linux, serial-port, pyserial, errno

I have a few serial ports that I am trying to open with python (ipython in particular). Running python 3.8.8 in Scientific Linu 7.9. I run it with the lines

```
import serial
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyr00', baudrate=57600, timeout=1)
```

and I receive the following error

```
SerialException: [Errno 6] could not open port /dev/ttyr00: [Errno 6] No such device or address: '/dev/ttyr00'
```

I don't really understand. If I run `ls -lart | grep ttyr` in  `/dev` I get
[image]
so it is showing up.

I have tried running `sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyr00` based on the answers of [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53375587/serial-serialutil-serialexception-could-not-open-port-dev-ttyama0-errno-13), but that was hopeful rather than expecting it to work (note I don't get the "Permission denied" error that OP does).

Any thoughts? I've had this issue before, but I can't recall how I solved it. I think I went into some file and changed something... I use two other `ttyr` ports, 2 and 3, and I'm getting the same issues with them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **Linux**:

To determine the required port, follow these steps:

Run the following command twice. First, make sure the board or dongle is unplugged, and then run it again after plugging it in. The port that appears the second time is the one you need:

```
ls /dev/tty*
```

If the above command does not work, you can try the following:

2. Ensure that the currently logged-in user has read and write access to the USB serial port. On most Linux distributions, this can be achieved by adding the user to the dialout group. Execute the following command:

   sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER

If you are using **MacOS**:

Perform the same procedure as mentioned above, but use the following command instead:

```
ls /dev/cu.*
```

Comment: Hi there, it is linux I'm using. It's a bit of a funny set up - I'm using a MOXA control unit to control some motors, and they're always plugged in. I ended up solving it in the end, it was an issue with the port mapping through this moxa unit. I will post an answer, although the setup is so specific it is unlikely to be of much help to people.